# image gets rotated on slideshow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using bootstrap carousel plugin to slideshow the photos. The problem is some images gets rotated by 90 degree,
Is there any way to solve the problem?

**Here is the html:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div id="firstCarousel" class="carousel" style="background-color:ghostwhite; border:solid white; box-shadow:0 0 30px">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#firstCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#firstCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#firstCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#firstCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          <li data-target="#firstCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
          <li data-target="#firstCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
          <li data-target="#firstCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/1873-min.JPG" class="img-responsive" style="height: 600px; width: 500px;" />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/1992.JPG" class="img-responsive" style="height: 600px; width: 500px;" />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/1993.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="height: 600px; width: 500px;" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#firstCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#firstCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the actual photo i uploaded:

[image]

And this is what i get on the website:

[image]

I ve disabled the manual height and width, but does not work.

Comment: This is showing exact image to me. No rotation.

Comment: so what might be the problem? yea some images show exact image but some shows rotated .

Comment: Then give me online link of your output here. http://codepen.io/

Comment: i will give u the original image link [link](https://postimg.org/image/aely8vc8n/)

Comment: All images are giving these result?

Comment: I am not finding any problem to me. Sorry. Why are you using this  style="height: 600px; width: 500px;? Because you use img-responsive class.

Comment: try to save pictures without EXIF and reset orientation on them (image editors are capable of doing this, like IrfanView)

Comment: I donot know whats wrong but changing jpg to png solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Details answering this at two links:
http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html
https://www.ivertech.com/Articles/Image-Rotation-Issue-With-Windows-10.aspx

Short summary - there is an orientation flag in JPG that is not honored by all display agents.  Carousel is one that does not, but Windows 10 does, so the image looks right in File Explorer, but is rotated in Carousel.  Two solutions given in the links, and explanation about why the rotate function in Windows tools doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Good day.  This happened to me as well and what I did was to save the image as web with the same file format into a different file using Photoshop.  Hope this helps. Thank you.