# Images rotated to horizontal by bootstrap carousel on desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap carousel 3.3.4 in a web application.  All the photos including vertical (portrait) are displayed horizontal on the desktop browser but appear correct on mobile browsers.

**This only seems to to happen for photos uploaded from a phone gallery that were actual photos taken with the camera.**

Same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813028/image-gets-rotated-on-slideshow) but only has issue on desktop when photo was taken on a phone camera.

This is the code I am using:

```
<div id="carousel-gallery" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pictures.Count; i++)
        {
        <li data-target="#carousel-gallery" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
        }
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pictures.Count; i++)
        {
        <div class="item @(i == 0 ? " active" : "" )">
            <img style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" alt="" src="@Model.Pictures[i].Url" data-holder-rendered="true">
        </div>
        }
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-gallery" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">[[[Previous]]]</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-gallery" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">[[[Next]]]</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

How do I get the images to show correctly as they were uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

I had to take into account that phones exif data can mess this up. I looked at the exif orientation when uploading the image then rotated according to that.  Then deleted the exif data.  I used [this](https://www.ryadel.com/en/change-image-orientation-iphone-andor-android-phone-pics-net-c/) code.